How to add hand mesh to a Hololens 2 app using Unity and MRTK3
I have a project in Unity for Hololens 2 which is using MRTK3 and I am trying to add a visualizer to my hands and cannot find any tutorial or explanation how to do this.
I tried to add the RiggedHandVisualizer.cs script to my hands inside the MRTK XR Rig but it seems that is not doing anything and I cannot figure out how to configure this script and how to make it to work.In MRTK2 I saw that you can enable/disable hand mesh and maybe in MRTK3 is a option like this but I can't see it. I tried to deploy the app on hololens with the hope that it is working only when the app is running on the headset but hand mesh is still missing.

You are on the right track with the RiggedHandVisualizer. It seems like they are purposely trying to avoid visualization on optical see-through devices which does make sense, since the slight delay between your actual hands and the visualization can be disturbing. Anyways, if you wanna play around or indeed need the visualization, here is how you can do it:
Visualizing your whole hand in the form of a virtual hand

Assuming you are using the MRTK XR Rig, go to:
MRTK XR Rig - Camera Offset - MRTK LeftHand Controller/MRTK RightHandController in your scene hierarchy
On the XRController component, scroll down to section Model
Under ModelPrefab you will see a transform already assigned e.g. openxr_right_hand. If interested, take a look at it. It has the RiggedHandMeshVisualizer component attached. You can see that by default ShowHandsOnTransparent is disabled which affects HL2
You can't/shouldn't modify it since it is in a readonly folder. However, you can duplicate the prefab and assign it on the XRController component instead. On that prefab, make sure to tick ShowHandsOnTransparent

Visualizing hand joints

To visualize joints on your hand, add the HandJointVisualizer script somewhere in your scene e.g. on your hand controllers
Assign a simple cube mesh as JointMesh and e.g. the HandJointMaterial provided by MRTK as the JointMaterial


The solution worked, I don't know how I didn't do this myself because I inspected the hand prefab, thanks :)
